# Is it recorded and/or documented when and where Curiosity's ChemCam's laser has zapped on Mars?

Tags: mars, curiosity, geology, laser

The article with the title ["NASA Rover's Images Show Laser Flash on Martian Rock"](https://nasa.gov/jpl/msl/laser-flash-20140716) tells us that the ChemCam's laser had zapped more than 600 rock and soil targets on Mars since Curiosity landed in August 2012.

Has it been recorded and/or documented at exactly what time the laser has zapped on those events ?

I would like to know this, then being able to distinguish possible white spots caused by the laser from other white spots on the surface of Mars on [Curiosity's raw images](https://mars.nasa.gov/msl/multimedia/raw-images/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course that has been recorded. MSL's science data is stored at the Planetary Datasystem. ChemCam data are [here](https://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/missions/msl/chemcam.htm).

The Analyst's notebook shows the data [on a map](https://an.rsl.wustl.edu/msl/mslbrowser/an3.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, especially the detailed traverse map will come in handy !  I only can't find time data.